# How do I make the Console app reappear after deleting Everything? OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, console

I deleted every file that was contained in the console's logs listing of my Macbook Pro 15, including the "All messages,".
 Now when I click to open the app, the program opens but no GUI will load. The only way I can get the GUI to load is to manually open a log file, and the tab under "System Log Queries" is empty.

Any clue how I can fix this to where the console GUI will load when I open the app? If I gesture down on the trackpad and it shows a blurry screen (as there is no open window). Can I just use the touch command to make a blank file for it to load to, and if so, where should I put it and under what name?

Comment: The message of the event of opening the console is `*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter`

Comment: It is not clear what you deleted, just the logs or more and where did you delete them.

Comment: It's not clear to me what I deleted, I thought I only deleted log files, but if I did, then why is it behaving as such? I deleted them by right clicking on each entry in the list (including "All Messages") and moving the contents of each folder to the trash then emptying the trash. I recreated the log query "All Messages" with a trap level of at least Debug. My previous comment was sort of incomplete, that message does appear, but the first message that gets logged is  `Failed to connect (_consoleX) outlet from (NSApplication) to (ConsoleX): missing setter or instance variable`

Comment: I ran out of room in the last comment. Each location would be /Library/logs, ~/Library/logs, /var/logs, /private/var/logs, and the contents of whatever folder "All Messages" was in.

Comment: The "All Messages" is (was) in the /Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/ASLQueries  as "All Messages.aslquery"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my newly created All\ Messages.aslquery to /Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/ASLQueries, closed and reopened console, and bam the GUI comes up. Thank you Buscar with providing me with the necessary file location to solve this problem.